# How to create Multiple indexes in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic search, I have a User class which has topic and expertise class as composite class.

```
public class User {
    private String auth0Id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Set<Topic> interests = new HashSet<Topic>();
    private Set<Expertise> expertise = new HashSet<Expertise>();
}
```

i fetch this from my db and want to index it. I have done following

```
Iterable<User> results = userService.getAll();
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
int i = 0;
Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
Client client = node.client();
    try {
        for (User userObj : results) {
        UserTO userTo = new UserTO();
        userTo = marshall(userObj);
        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("member","member")
                            .setSource(mapper.writeValueAsString(userTo)).execute()
                            .actionGet();
        i++;
        log.debug("User/Member " + userObj.getEmail() + " (" + response.getId() + ") has been updated");
        }
        log.info(i + " user/members indexed");
        log.info(i + " user/members indexed");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I want to add index on interest and expertise to, so that when user search on name or expertise or interest all user having name or expertise or interest should be shown.

Comment: You want to index the topic data to a different index than "member" ? or just to be able to search on the topics, inside of the "member" index?

Comment: yes. scenario is such that if a topic is searched a user having that topic should be shown another scenario is if user name is search that user should be shown.

Comment: Is it part of the marshal().. results? does the JSON include the topics field?
Can you specify the index mapping by GET <host>/member/_mapping and add it to the question? 
Also add to the question the query you're running